# Como detectar cuando el usuario scrollea hasta el bottom del sitio?

Tags: reactjs

De que formas podria detectar en mi componente cuando el usuario hace scroll y llega al final del sitio y de esa forma llamar una funcion cuando esto pase?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ocupar la funcion affix de js para generar efectos al mover el scroll.
te dejo un ejemplo con [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-events) que emula lo que estas buscando, en el ejemplo basicamente los bloques de colores serian el bootom de tu pagina, ya depende que funcion o estilo desencadenas.

```
$('#footer').affix({
offset: {
top: 100, //estilos
bottom: function () {
  return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true)) //eventos
}
```

}
})

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy_affix&stacked=h

Comment: Podrias explicar mejor tu codigo? Que vendria a ser #myAffix? Sobre el ejemplo de bootstrap, no quiero usar bootstrap en lo posible y ademas lo que necesito es sobre una simple pagina al ir al bootom de esa pagina ejecutar una accion, como ejemplo puede ser tirar un alert. Para que quiero esto? Porque mi sitio carga items de 5 en 5 y quiero que al llegar al bottom del sitio se carguen 5 items mas y asi. Pero lo que no he podido encontrar es la forma de detectar cuando el user llega al bottom

Comment: __#myAffix__ vendria siendo el id del contenedor que en tu caso seria el footer
si no usas id solo agregas __$('footer')__ o el nombre de tu contenedor
en el offset el codigo alert o eventos que esto conlleva.

Comment: Bien, gracias. Me tira este error ahora: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).affix is not a function

Comment: no olvides importar la libreria de bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0):

Dejo mi solucion, y lo mas importante. Sin bootstrap, por si alguien la encesita.

```js
let container = document.getElementById('body');

container.onscroll = function () {
  let height = this.clientHeight;
  let scrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
  let scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
  
  if (height + scrollTop === scrollHeight) {
    viewMore()
    }
  }

}
```